# Is it possible to filter foreignkeys with a queryset? Django

Tags: django

I just updated django from 1.8.5 to 1.10.
In the old Version i used a filter to search for entries regarding more then one location. For example:

One User has multiple Stores. Each of this Stores has a Reviews Board. 
Now the User wants to lookup all Stores and their Reviews or specific Groups of Stores.

In Django 1.8.5 i used the following lookup:

all stores

```
locations = Locations.objects.filter(email=email)
```

locations queryset(location1, location2 etc.)

```
reviews = Reviews.objects.filter(location_id=locations)
```

group

```
reviews = Reviews.objects.filter(location_id=group_content.locations.all())
```

In Reviews the location field is a ForeignKey(Locations) and locations is a Queryset.

This worked just fine. However in 10.10 it appears this functionality is gone.
I looked through the new Docs but could not find anything which could replicate the original functionality.

My whole System is built around this functionality, so it would take forever to change everything.

Is there any new Lookup i could use?

models.py (Reviews):

```
class Reviews(models.Model):
    location_adress = models.CharField(max_length=3000, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=3000, default='', blank=True, null=True)

    location_id =  models.ForeignKey(LocationData)
    plattform =  models.CharField(max_length=3000, default='', blank=True, null=True)

    reviewer_name = models.CharField(max_length=3000, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    reviewer_picture = models.CharField(max_length=3000, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    review_id =  models.CharField(max_length=3000, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    review_rating =  models.CharField(max_length=3000, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    review_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
    review_text = models.CharField(max_length=3000, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    review_like_count = models.CharField(max_length=3000, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    review_share_count = models.CharField(max_length=3000, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    review_comment_count = models.CharField(max_length=3000, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    review_image = models.CharField(max_length=3000, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    next_entry =  models.CharField(max_length=3000, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    unseen_comments_count = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(ReviewComments)
    scale = models.IntegerField(default=None,blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location_name
```

modely.py (Locations)

```
   class LocationData(models.Model):
        #Location Data
        group_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='', blank=True, null=True)
        location_id =  models.CharField(max_length=120, default='', blank=True, null=True)
        email = models.EmailField()
        name = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='', blank=True, null=True)
        street = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='', blank=True, null=True)
        street_number = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='', blank=True, null=True)
        opening = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
        tel = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='', blank=True, null=True)
        postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='', blank=True, null=True)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='', blank=True, null=True)
        country = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='', blank=True, null=True)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=1120, default='', blank=True, null=True)
        short_description = models.CharField(max_length=1120, default='', blank=True, null=True)
        website = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='', blank=True, null=True)
        location_email = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='', blank=True, null=True)
        tags = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='', blank=True, null=True)
        profilbild = models.CharField(max_length=320, default='', blank=True, null=True)
        titelbild = models.CharField(max_length=320, default='', blank=True, null=True)
  def __str__(self): #Python 3.3 is __str__
    return self.name
```

Result:

```
    >>> from reviews.models import Reviews
    >>> from locations.models import LocationData
    >>> l = LocationData.objects.all()
    >>> Reviews.objects.filter(location_id=l)
    <QuerySet [<Reviews: Bspotted>, <Reviews: Bspotted>, <Reviews: Bspotted>, <Reviews: Bspotted>, <Reviews: Bspotted>, <Reviews: Bspotted>, <Reviews: Bspotted>, <Reviews: Bspotted>, <Reviews: Bspotted>]>

>>> Reviews.objects.filter(location_id=l[0])
<QuerySet [<Reviews: Bspotted>, <Reviews: Bspotted>, <Reviews: Bspotted>, <Reviews: Bspotted>, <Reviews: Bspotted>, <Reviews: Bspotted>, <Reviews: Bspotted>, <Reviews: Bspotted>, <Reviews: Bspotted>]>
>>> Reviews.objects.filter(location_id=l[1])
<QuerySet [<Reviews: Roberto American Bar>, <Reviews: Roberto American Bar>, <Reviews: Roberto American Bar>, <Reviews: Roberto American Bar>, <Reviews: Roberto American Bar>, <Reviews: Roberto American Bar>, <Reviews: Roberto American Bar>, <Reviews: Roberto American Bar>, <Reviews: Roberto American Bar>, <Reviews: Roberto American Bar>, <Reviews: Roberto American Bar>, <Reviews: Roberto American Bar>, <Reviews: Roberto American Bar>, <Reviews: Roberto American Bar>, <Reviews: Roberto American Bar>, <Reviews: Roberto American Bar>, <Reviews: Roberto American Bar>, <Reviews: Roberto American Bar>, <Reviews: Roberto American Bar>, <Reviews: Roberto American Bar>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

Comment: If you get some error post it in the question.

Comment: @Todor no errors, just not the desired result

Comment: @Todor updated the Result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

l is a queryset, not a single object, so you should do something like that:

```
Reviews.objects.filter(location__in=l)
```